# Access to svg from D3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So I have an SVG image(3 circles) generated from data with D3 library.

```
var myData = [1,2,3];
var svgViewport = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width","600").attr("height","600"); 
var circleSelection = svgViewport.selectAll("circle").data(myData); 
var circleElements = circleSelection.enter().append("circle");

circleElements.attr("cx",function(d,i) { 
    return d * 100; 
})
    .attr("cy",function(d,i) { 
        return d * 50; 
    })
    .attr("r","35");

function greenBlue(d,i) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) { 
        return "green"; 
    }
    else { 
        return "blue"; 
    };
}

greenBlue(1,2);
var circleStyle = circleElements.style("fill",greenBlue);
```

I want to when I mouse over an element it will change color. I know how to do it when elements are in HTML file, but I want to know how it

```
document.getElementById("info").onmouseover = function() {
mouseOver()};
```

can be replaced in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, start by reading the [d3 documentation on event handling](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#handling-events), which will bring you to the documentation for the `.on` method. So, if you'd like to change the color on mouseover, you'd use on, and `this`:

```
circleElements.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
});
```

This example is nearly verbatim [the example in the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#select).